# Splitting words over multiple rows based on amount

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For example: I have 550 words in row A. I want the values in row A to be splitted over 6 rows. Row B, C, D, E, F containing 100, row G containing 50 words.

Background: For a keyword research I need the search volume for all those keywords using Google's Keyword Planner. There is a limit on how much keywords you can enter in one time. Splitting them over rows will make it much easier & faster to copy/paste the values. Usually the amount ranges between 50k-90k.

Thanks for thinking along!

Comment: Hi , Welcome to SO. As SO is not a code writing service, you have to provide us with what you have tried so far and we can help you with any issues with your code/formula's. Also, I suspect you searched for an answer before you posted your query? I only ask because I remember answering something similar to this

Comment: Are all words stored in a single cell? What have you tried so far? A for loop would do your work. Also note that excel has ~16K column limit.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the words are split in the cells across the top row. If the words are in a single cell you can split them using Data > Text to Columns:

[image: Text to columns]

To do this with formulas (not VBA code), enter formulas in cell in A2-A7 as follows A2: =A$1, A3: =CW$1, A4: =GS$1, A5: =KO$1, A6: =OK$1, A7: =SG$1.  Then select cells A2 to A7 and drag the drag handle horizontally to column CV.

[image: Formula view]

Result:

[image: Result]

This is clearer if you change to R1C1 formula reference style (File > Options > Formulas > Working with formulas > R1C1 reference style):

[image]

[image: R1C1 reference style option]